# TYPO3 - extending an extbase extension with new fields and using these in fluid templates

Tags: fluid, extbase

I'm trying to extend powermail (version 2) with the possibility to add a note for each input field. So far I have created a new extension using extension builder and with a few modifications to ext_tables.php the field show up in the backend. The new field is called 'note' and I thought I could just do something like {field.note} in the fluid template input.html, but that does not work. My model includes the setter and getter:

class Tx_Formnotes_Domain_Model_Powermailnotes extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity {

```
/**
 * note
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $note;

/**
 * Returns the note
 *
 * @return string $note
 */
public function getNote() {
    return $this->note;
}

/**
 * Sets the note
 *
 * @param string $note
 * @return void
 */
public function setNote($note) {
    $this->note = $note;
}
```

}

What else is needed?

Info: I'm using TYPO3 4.7

Answer (score 0):

You could map the powermail model like

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {

Tx_Formnotes_Domain_Model_Powermailnotes {
    mapping {
        tableName = powermailTableName
        columns {
            exampleMedia.mapOnProperty = media
        }
    }
}
}
```

after that you should extend your TCA with these properties. At least you can write setter and getter for each property and use them in your fluid template.

Comment: What do you mean by "extend you TCA". Do I have to do more than what is already created by the extension builder?

Comment: you must add your mapping fields to access these prperties with setters or getters.